# How to calculate a Date given only month, week number within that month, and day of week

Tags: javascript, date

I am calling an api that returns the following object to tell me that daylight savings time begins on March 11th for a given timezone:

```
{
  dayOfWeek: "Sunday",
  month: 3,
  timeOfDay: "0001-01-01T02:00:00.000Z",
  week: 2
}
```

where week:2 reprsents the 2nd week of March in this case.

How do I create March 11th from this?  I have the following function which works fine for March, but realized this would fail for April if say the api returned the following:

```
{
  dayOfWeek: "Saturday",
  month: 4,
  timeOfDay: "0001-01-01T02:00:00.000Z",
  week: 2
}
```

Code:

```
/**
 * Given the year, month, week day, week number of the month, and time, calculate a date
    - set the date to the first day of the month
    - then adjust the date backwards to the proper weekday
    - then move it forward by 7 * week number to get it to the proper date
 */
calcDateFromDaylightSavingRulesAPI: function(year, month, time, dayOfWeek, weekNum) {
    const weekDays = {
        Sunday: 0,
        Monday: 1,
        Tuesday: 2,
        Wednesday: 3,
        Thursday: 4,
        Friday: 5,
        Saturday: 6
    };

    const date = new Date(year, month, 1, time);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + weekDays[dayOfWeek] - date.getDay());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + (weekNum * constants.DAYS_PER_WEEK));

    return date;
```

Comment: How will your function fail? What will it return? And what do you want instead?

Comment: And what year are you testing with?

Comment: @code-apprentice It would return April 21st instead of April 14th since the line which is supposed to adjust it backwards by a day, actually adjusts it forward 6 days.  I am just debuggined in chrome to do my testing.

Comment: I added the following code and it seems to work, but I'm not convinced it would work in all cases:
const diff = weekDays[dayOfWeek] - date.getDay();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + (diff > 0 ? diff - 7 : diff));

Comment: What exactly is meant by week of month?  On what day do weeks start?  And how do you handle a week that starts in the previous month and continues into the current one?

Comment: I wasn't asking **how** you are testing. I was trying to clarify your example input data. None of them contains a year value.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - year is hard coded to today's year.  I realized after I posted I should have clarified that

Comment: @ScottSauyet - per my comment "where week:2 represents the 2nd week of March in this case", it's the week within the month, so 1 is the first week of the month, 2 is the second week of the month, etc..  A week that starts in the previous month is the last week of that month.  It depends on the timezone, but let's assume for simplicity that the week starts on Sunday

Comment: @PaulFabbroni So if Mar 1 is on Wed, what is the "week of the month" for each of the days from Mar 1 to March 8?

Comment: So this does not help you get, for instance, "the first Friday of March", since that would would actually be listed in the last week of February?  And likewise the fourth Friday of February would actually be in March?  Is this ok?

Comment: It's unclear whether you want the second Sunday or the Sunday of the second week. The first is much easier to calculate, which do you want?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - I'll have to check with the guys who wrote the api.  Let's use March 1st being a Thursday though since that matches our time right now (2018).  So my guess is Mar 1st-3rd would be the last week of Feb and Mar 4th-10th would be the 1st week of March.  Since they are currently passing me "week 2" as the week that has March 11th, I have a feeling they are counting Sundays i.e. Sunday March 4th begins week 1, March 11th begins week 2, etc.  Strange logic that I'll have to confirm with them.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - correct.  I believe in that case they would pass me month = 2, week = 4, weekday = friday.  Which I think would make my code wrong because I would set the date to Feb 1st, adjust it back to Jan 26th, then add 4 weeks, which would put it at Feb 23rd instead of March 2nd. I'll have to test that out.

Comment: @RobG - In this example, Sunday from the 2nd week of March.  I'll have to confirm with the api guys how they are defining weeks, but it appears to be full weeks that start on Sunday, so March 4th is week 1, March 11th is week 2, etc.

Comment: I can't seem to edit my question.  I just heard back from a guy on the api team and he wasn't quite sure lol.  He said they are using this library: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.getadjustmentrules(v=vs.110).aspx  and here is a copy of their code (not sure if this is publicly accessible): https://git.geotab.com/dev/Development/blob/master/Checkmate/CheckmateServer/Web/WebMethods.cs#

Comment: I think I got it now.  Week doesn't equal full weeks or weeks that start on Sunday, or anything like that.  It represents which week you want from that month and weekday is which day you want i.e. in my example I want the 2nd Sunday of March since month =3, weekday = sunday, and week  =2.  So March 1st for example wouldn't return the 4th week of february as I mentioned above, it would return the 1st week of march i.e. month: 3, dayOfWeek: Thursday, week: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is working correctly now.  Thanks for your help everyone!

```
/**
 * Given an object which contains month, time, week day, and week number in a month, calculate a date
    - set the date to the first day of the month
    - then adjust the date backwards to the proper weekday
    - then move it forward by 7 * week number to get it to the proper date
 */
calcDateFromDaylightSavingRulesAPI: function(ruleSet) {
    const today = new Date();
    const year = today.getFullYear();
    const month = ruleSet.month - 1;
    const time = new Date(ruleSet.timeOfDay).getUTCHours();
    const dayOfWeek = ruleSet.dayOfWeek;
    const weekNum = ruleSet.week;

    const weekDays = {
        Sunday: 0,
        Monday: 1,
        Tuesday: 2,
        Wednesday: 3,
        Thursday: 4,
        Friday: 5,
        Saturday: 6
    };

    const date = new Date(year, month, 1, time);
    const diff = weekDays[dayOfWeek] - date.getDay();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + (diff >= 0 ? diff - 7 : diff));
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + (weekNum * constants.DAYS_PER_WEEK));

    return date;
},
```

Comment: You need to be careful with how you are getting the daylight saving start time, there's no rule that it must start on an even hour (and not all daylight saving offsets are 1 hour). Rather than using the internal parser and Date methods, I think it would be better to get the hours and minutes from the timestamp using string methods, e.g. `ruleSet.timeOfDay.match(/\d\d:\d\d/).split(':')`. Simpler and less error prone.

Comment: @RobG - the api returns the time in UTC format and incorporates timezone, DST, etc.

Comment: UTC isn't a format, it's a standard, your string is in ISO 8601 extended format. ;-) I just think it's not necessary to create a Date and use its methods to get back data that was in the string in the first place. In the example you've provided, the API data is UTC and you're using UTC methods, so effectively no timezone. You're just using it for the start hour and applying it to the host timezone. I'm in UTC+1000, so if daylight saving was to start here at 02:00 that would be 12:00 Z, but I think your API would pass it as 02:00. Complete guess of course… ;-)

Comment: Semantics ;)... There's more stuff that goes on before I call this method involving timezones utc etc.  I can't remember why I needed to do that, but I'm pretty sure I did.  Maybe you're right and I can remove it.  Either way I think it's irrelevant to the main part of my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the nth occurrence of a particular day in a month, you can get the 1st of the month, move to the first occurrence of the particular day, then add `(n-1) * 7` days to get to the nth occurrence, e.g.

```js
function getNthDay(year, month, dayName, n) {
  var weekDays = {
        Sunday: 0,
        Monday: 1,
        Tuesday: 2,
        Wednesday: 3,
        Thursday: 4,
        Friday: 5,
        Saturday: 6
    };
  // validate input values here, throw errors if required, e.g.
  // dayName must be in weekdays, 0 < n < 6 

  // Create date for first day of required month
  var d = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
  
  // Set to first instance of particular day
  d.setDate((8 - (d.getDay() - weekDays[dayName]))%7);
  
  // Add (n-1)*7 days
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + (n-1) * 7);
  
  // Check final date is still in required month
  return d.getMonth() == month - 1? d : 'fail';
}

// Second Sunday in March, 2018
console.log(getNthDay(2018,3,'Sunday',2).toString())
```

If you want the Sunday of the second week, that is a little harder to calculate since some places start weeks on Sunday, and some on Monday. Also, the algorithm for the week of the month may change from place to place (as does week in year).

Comment: Ya that's pretty much what I'm doing except I'm going backwards and multiplying by n instead of going forwards and multiplying by n-1.  Thanks though!